# Авторизация oAuth

Tags: oauth

На многих сайтах доступны кнопки авторизации через вконтакте, гугл, итд. Я прочитал спецификацию технологии и изучил исходный код проекта авторизации oauth приложения на php, но на сколько я понял, в том проекте можно авторизоваться либо во вконтакте, либо в целевом сайте, но не в одном через другое. Можно ли приложению использовать авторизацию вконтакте для авторизации на целевом сайте? Если можно, то какой должен быть сценарий обмена запросами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строго говоря, речь идёт о аутентификации, а не о авторизации. Говоря о авторизации, вы подразумеваете предоставление доступа к ресурсам пользователя А пользователем A пользователю В. Аутентификация - это же процесс удостоверения того, что пользователь А действительно пользователь А.

Если говорить о аутентификации с помощью внешних аутентифицирующих агентов (типа социальных сетей, таких как ВК), то да, это безусловно возможно.

Существует стандарт аутентификации методами OAuth2.0 от OpenID ([здесь](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html)). Данный стандарт наиболее точно и полно описывает все необходимые действия при аутентифицировании пользователя на клиенте (вашем сайте) с помощью внешнего аутентифицирующего агента (например, ВК).

Данный протокол несколько переусложнён в случае, если вы используете Authorization Code Grant (см. описание [здесь](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)). Кратко опишу его упрощённую версию:

1. Пользователь хочет аутентифицироваться на клиенте (вашем сайте)
2. Клиент перенаправляет пользователя на внешний аутентифицирующий агент (ВК).
3. Пользователь аутентифицируется и авторизует клиента на доступ к некоторым своим ресурсам (к примеру, email)
4. Внешний аутентифицирующий агент перенаправляет пользователя на клиент, передаёт авторизационный код
5. Клиент получает код, обменивает его у агента на токен доступа.
6. Клиент запрашивает у агента информацию о клиенте с использованием токена доступа (site.com/userinfo)
7. Агент возвращает информацию (к примеру, email пользователя) и клиент считает, что пришедший пользователь именно тот, чью информацию от агента он получил.

Данный протокол несколько двусмысленен, так как в некотором смысле приравнивает авторизацию ресурса и аутентификацию, однако он наиболее распространён. При использовании полного протокола OpenID Connect Basic эта неприятность несколько сглаживается. В случае, если это критично, стоит использовать сам OpenID Connect. Он уже поддерживается большим количеством сервисов.

Answer (score 1):

После авторизации во Вконтакте через oAuth на страничку, указанную в параметрах передается редирект с гет параметрами. Проверяешь полученный код попробовав получить access_token. Если получился - забираешь оттуда имя, логин и авторизуешь пользователя.

Comment: access_token  из вк может пригодится только для того чтобы дёргать местные методы. Да, допустим, я узнаю имя или логин, но что именно нужно делать после того, как я авторизовался вк?

Comment: например. создаешь учетку в своей системе с логином от вконтакта и каким-то хешем в пароле. если учетка с таким логином есть - то авторизуешь его по хешу